# tools for remote linux based machines for compiling C/C++ projects

Tags: c++, c, build-process, build-automation, distributed-computing

I have 2 machines, i would like to use the most powerful one only when I need it and only for compiling purposes.

Right now I'm only interested in C/C++ projects and in the support for gcc and clang, I also would like to avoid networking filesystems, my idea is more about an automated sync between 2 machines rather than working on a shared network folder.

My question is: there is a suite that can fit my needs ? There are building tools that can be better integrated with this suite such as cmake or make ?

If this is important, I use `vim` and/or `QtCreator` for my projects.

Comment: You could use rsync together with the ssh command

Comment: distcc http://code.google.com/p/distcc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know of any suite for your specific needs, the standard *nix toolchain will do well here.

- If you want to directly synchronize some directories on both machines, see [rysnc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync).
- Another (probably better) idea would be to use version control - such as [Git](http://git-scm.com). If you're not using it already, version control is critical to any serious project. Its main purpose is to synchronize code across multiple machines and users.

You could combine either of the options above with some scripts (in bash, zsh, python, whatever you prefer) and schedule said scripts with something like [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Bam - automated builds.

Comment: yes, it can be a solution, but basically you are proposing to use my remote machine as I already use my local machine the only difference is that i will use my remote machine through ssh; my point is different, I would like to input commands on my local machine and using the remote one only for compiling.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for distcc:
[distcc project page at google code](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/)

(link also contains basic instructions for setting things up)